# Custom paging outside jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I want to have custom paging control outside the jqgrid.How can i achieve below style paging.On scroll it will load next 10 records and on(But the mvc controller is returning entire json record at once)..and also on clicking "view all" it will load all records .And the paging control should be outside the jqgrid.
Help is much appreciated.
Please refer the image below!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just `reloadGrid` with `page` parameter to display the data from specified page:

```
$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid", { page: newPageNumber });
```

See the simple demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/a64yzdc5/1/, where you can click on the buttons "1", "2" and "3" to switch the page on the grid below the buttons.