# How to refresh jqgrid and go back to the current page using loadonce: true

Tags: jqgrid

I am using the following setting which loads all the data from the server at once:

```
loadonce: true
```

Now I attempt to reload the grid after an edit:

```
// options for the Edit Dialog
{
 closeAfterEdit: true,
 closeOnEscape: true,
 reloadAfterSubmit: true,
 editCaption: "Edit User",
 width: 1140,
 height: 370,
 afterSubmit: function () {
                       $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                       return [true,'']; // no error
                   },
 errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                       return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                                  }
},
```

The data is refreshed from the server however, there is an issue:  For example, If I edit a record in page 2, it shows page 2 on the navbar on the bottom but it always brings up the data from page 1. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

**Update #1**

I tried the following code:

```
var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam");
p.datatype = "json";
$self.trigger("reloadGrid", { page: p.page, current: true });
```

Then I edit and click on submit, it still loads page 1 data even though the navbar stays on page 2.  Then I click the forward arrow to go to page 3, then the back arrow to go to page 2 again and now it shows the page 2 data.

**Update #2**

Here is additional relevant code of all I am doing and still not working:

```
...

cmTemplate: { editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true } },
            pager: "#jqGridPager",
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'lastName, firstName',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            width: 1140,
            height: "auto",
            multiselect: false,
            altRows: false,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            scroll: false
            }
        });
...

        $('#jqGrid').navGrid('#jqGridPager',
               // the buttons to appear on the toolbar of the grid
               {
                   edit: true,
                   add: true,
                   del: true,
                   search: true,
                   view: true,
                   refresh: true,
                   position: "left",
                   cloneToTop: false,
                   beforeRefresh: function () {
                       //Note: This function is only called after user clicks the refresh button
                       $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                   }
               },
               // Options for the Edit Dialog
               {
                   closeAfterEdit: true,
                   closeOnEscape: true,
                   reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                   editCaption: "Edit User",
                   width: 1140,
                   height: 370,
                   afterSubmit: function () {
                       var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam");
                       p.datatype = "json";
                       $self.trigger("reloadGrid", { page: p.page, current: true });
                       return [true, '']; // no error
                   },
                   errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                       return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                   }
               },
...
```

**FINAL OUTCOME**

I finally got the issue resolved!  I switched from the not free [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) to [free jqGrid by Oleg](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) and the bug was gone!  I originally could not get the navigation buttons to appear on the free jqgrid but the reason they didnt appear is because I had the tag iconSet: "fontAwesome" and I did not reference that font.  When I removed that tag completely, everything worked perfect.  You can use that tag but you must reference the iconset url.  In my case I did not need a different icon set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `page` option of `reloadGrid` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42207362/315935) for the corresponding demo). You can use `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "page")` to get `page` parameter, which hold *the current* page.

```js
afterSubmit: function () {
    var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam");
    p.datatype = "json";
    $self.trigger("reloadGrid", { page: p.page, current: true });
    return [true]; // no error
}
```

I used `current: true` option of `reloadGrid` to select the currently selected row after reloading of the grid.

Comment: Thank you Oleg! Please check "Update #1" per your suggestion.

Comment: @RobertSmith: You are welcome! I think you should examine other options, which you use. For example, you should use `reloadAfterSubmit: false`, because you prefer that *your code from afterSubmit* reloads the grid yourself. You current option `reloadAfterSubmit: true` makes **the second** reload, which is the origin of the strange behavior.

Comment: Oleg, I set it to false but did not work. I placed all relevant code above.  Thank you.

Comment: @RobertSmith: It's difficult to help you because I don't can *debug* the code. In any way, 1) it's better to place the code with `reloadGrid` inside of `setTimeout(function () {...});`. It allows jqGrid to finish the standard processing of `afterSubmit` and to process `reloadGrid` later. 2) You should include the information about the version of jqGrid, which you use, and the fork of jqGrid, which you use, in all your questions. 3) I suppose that you have some effect related reloading the data from the server. which format have the data? I suppose processing of server response is your problem.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  I am using jqGrid  5.1.1.  It is definitely not a server side issue though.

Comment: @RobertSmith: I means the you could have the problem with *processing of the server response* and not any problem on the server side. I mean that the `page` number will be send to the server and then the current page will be **reset** by processing the server response. Everything will be easier if you prepare small JSFiddle demo, which do what you need. Having the demo I could modify it to make it working. Moreover you bought **commercial** [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), but I develop (and know :-)) alternative fork [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)

Comment: Oleg, I loaded up your free grid and all the navigation buttons (edit, view, search) disappeared.  Also the page selector disappeared so I can only see page 1 data.

Comment: @RobertSmith: The navigation buttons (edit, view, search) disappeared typically only if you didn't included correct jqGrid CSS or JS files. I can help you if you share the demo, which reproduce the problem. Free jqGrid is compatible to old jqGrid, but it contains additional features, which allows to reduce the code. [The page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) provide some examples of the usage.

Comment: @RobertSmith: The demo https://jsfiddle.net/chv7d1vs/1/ is the simple modification of the first demo from [the page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html). The main difference: it uses Echo service of JSFiddle to load the data "from the server" via HTTP POST. You can simulate any effects of the usage `loadonce: true`.

Comment: Oleg thank you for all your help. I could not get it to work.  Unfortunately I ended up having to go back to page 1 after an update.  That is the only way it would work:  afterSubmit: function (){ $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1 }]);...

Comment: @RobertSmith: By usage `.trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1 }]);` (or `.trigger('reloadGrid', { page: 1 });`) you **explicitly reset** the page number to 1 after reloading of the data from the server instead of going to **the current page**. Your question was: how to prevent the behavior: "How to refresh jqgrid and **go back to the current page** using loadonce: true". Isn't so?

Comment: @RobertSmith: Try your scenario on https://jsfiddle.net/chv7d1vs/3/ . One sees that the data will be reloaded from the server and one can stay on **the current page**. I repeat that the data returned from the server *don't contain* `page` parameter, which could be the only possible problem in your scenario.

Comment: Oleg, correct, the data coming back from the server is always the same.  I do not send back page information to the client since I am using loadonce = true.  I was trying to control the page number from the client only.  Is that possible? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @RobertSmith: I repeat, that I can't reproduce any problem. The code, which I posted in my answer work without any problem. I created the demo for you (see https://jsfiddle.net/chv7d1vs/3/ and earlier from my previous comments). One can reload the data from `afterSubmit` and still stay on the current page or on any other page (you can comment `$self.trigger("reloadGrid", { page: p.page, current: true });` and to use `$self.trigger("reloadGrid", { page: 3 });` instead). Thus I see really no problem. If you do have some problem that you have to share the demo, which reproduce it.

Comment: Oleg, finally I resolved the issue by switching to your free grid.  By the way, in case you run into this in the future, the reason the navigation buttons did not show up is because I had the tag iconSet: "fontAwesome" and I did not have a reference to those fonts.  You might want to make a change to your code where as if the iconSet fonts are not located, you default to the original fonts.  Once I removed that tag everything worked perfect.  Also I recommend renaming your grid to a unique name to avoid confusion with the other product.  Something like olegGrid, etc.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RobertSmith: You are welcome! The name of the product, which I develop, is "free jqGrid". By the way I published yesterday the new version 4.14.0. There are alternative commercial product under the name "Guriddo jqGrid JS" (see the prices and the licenses [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). There are NO "jqGrid" more. The last version of jqGrid was 4.7. The later versions exist either as "free jqGrid" or as "Guriddo jqGrid JS". `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` just use some other classes for some icons. There are no safe way to detect that there are exist some CSS rules for the classes.

Comment: @RobertSmith: If you are beginner in free jqGrid, then I recommend you to read [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html). I recommend you to read [new features](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid#new-main-features-implemented-in-the-version-4140-compared-with-4136) of version 4.14.0 because someone could be interestion for you too. By the way, is your problem is solved now? Then you should ["accept"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I marked your answer as accepted and have downloaded the latest version 4.14.0.  Good job.

Comment: Oleg, quick question, is there documentation on the "formEditing" as noted in the jsfiddle you created above?  And also should we be using this format instead of the "edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true,.." format?  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertSmith: The options `inlineEditing`, `formEditing`, `formViewing`, `formDeleting`, `searching`, `navOptions` and `actionsNavOptions` are old. I described the options and the reason of introduction of the option in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods). The option `formEditing` can be used to specify default options or callbacks of the method `editGridRow`, which could be called directly of indirectly (by `navGrid` or `formatter: "actions"`, for example).

Comment: @RobertSmith: If you familiar with TypeScript (at least on the base syntax level) then you will find [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.0/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L782-L838) the description of possible options which can be used inside of `formEditing`.